# Why aren't my profile and bashrc files hidden?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, mojave

I've been following tutorials to edit `.profile`, `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` and I discovered that my computer has `profile`, `bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files instead.
i.e. Only the `.bash_profile` file is hidden.

However, I've been able to follow these tutorials just fine, I just edit my `profile` file instead of `.profile`, and `bashrc` instead of `.bashrc`.

Is there a reason why these files are not hidden for me? And does it actually matter?

The thing I am confused about is that `.profile` and `profile` are two different files (from my understanding - e.g. I can use the `touch` command to create `.profile` and `profile`, then when I use the `ls` command to view these files, they are separate files.

So shouldn't there be an error from the terminal/bash initialisation program that's looking for `.profile` and `.bashrc`, since I only have `profile` and `bashrc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There are no **mandatory** startup files, `bash` will happily start up without `.bashrc` or `.profile`
- `bash` doesn't read your `profile` or `bashrc` files at all.

From `man bash`:

```
FILES
   /bin/bash
          The bash executable
   /etc/profile
          The systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells
   ~/.bash_profile
          The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
   ~/.bashrc
          The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
   ~/.bash_logout
          The individual login shell cleanup file, executed when a login shell exits
   ~/.inputrc
          Individual readline initialization file
```

Only the executable is really needed (for obvious reasons), all the others are optional, and `bash` doesn't care about other files with similar names. You may get a rather limited shell if `/etc/profile` is missing but even then `bash` will start up.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you.

Furthermore, after I spent more time reading `man bash` myself, I discovered this:
`The following paragraphs describe how bash executes its startup  files.
       If  any  of  the files exist but cannot be read, bash reports an error.
       Tildes are expanded in file names as described below under Tilde Expan-
       mands  from  the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading
       that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
       file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.`

Answer (score 1):

> However, I've been able to follow these tutorials just fine, I just
>   edit my profile file instead of .profile, and bashrc instead of
>   .bashrc.
>
> Is there a reason why these files are not hidden for me? And does it
>   actually matter?

**Yes to both questions.**

Basically `.bashrc` ≠ `bashrc`

(same hold true for the other files mentioned as well)

[A Unix dot-file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory) (`.filename`) is treated as a hidden file.  The dot preceding the filename is actually part of the filename itself; it's just interpreted by the system to be hidden.

To look at it another way, it's as if you used any other character at the beginning of the filename (a dash for example).  `-filename` is a very different file from `filename`.

So, when you say you've edited your `profile`, your actually editing the wrong file, you need to edit your `.profile`.

There's an excellent post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment) that explains when to use `.bashrc` and  `.bash_profile`

> So shouldn't there be an error from the terminal/bash initialisation
>   program that's looking for `.profile` and `.bashrc`, since I only have
>   `profile` and `bashrc`?

You're not getting an error message because there's no error

- these files are *optional*
- `.profile` and `.bashrc` don't exist (see above)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and links to further information. Interesting how MacOS runs a login shell everytime, which is different from UNIX!

Comment: It doesn't run a login shell every time...it runs an *interactive non-login shell*.  If it was a login shell, you'd have to enter your username/password every time.  macOS is not different than Unix, because it is a [certified Unix](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/brand3648.htm)